# Using onchange event inside php

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I am trying to use a onchange event inside php but it doens't work but i need to use the php to get data from my db.So how can obtain $patient[1] and $patient[2] to variables in javascript when I select a option?

```
if(!isset($_GET['enfermeiro'])){
    echo'<form action="index.php?opcao=user_update_succ" method="post" name="frmupdate">
            <p><select name="pacients" id="patients_list" onchange="alert("something")">
                <optgroup label="patients">
                ';for($i=0;$i<$pacients_number;$i++){
                    $patient=mysql_fetch_array($table_pacients);
                    echo '<option value="'.$patient[0].'">'."(".$patient[0].")(".$patient[1].")(".$patient[2].')</option>';

                };



                echo'</optgroup>
            </select><input type="checkbox" name="update_patient" value="1"></p>
            <br><p><select name="medics">
                <optgroup label="medics">
                    ';for($k=0;$k<$medics_number;$k++){
                        $medic=mysql_fetch_array($table_medic);
                        echo '<option value="'.$medic[0].'">'."(".$medic[0].")(".$medic[1].")(".$medic[2].')</option>';
                    };
                echo '</optgroup>
            </select><input type="checkbox" name="update_medic" value="1"></p>
            <input type="submit" value="update user">
        </form>';
}
```

Comment: onchange event you need to use ajax for this case

Answer (score 0):

**1. You should insert the data you want as attribute in your option. PHP**

```
       <select name="pacients" id="patients_list" >
            <optgroup label="patients">
            ';for($i=0;$i<$pacients_number;$i++){
                $patient=mysql_fetch_array($table_pacients);
/*  look here */  echo '<option value="'.$patient[0].'" data-pat1="'.$patient[1].'" data-pat2="'.$patient[2].'" >'."(".$patient[0].")(".$patient[1].")(".$patient[2].')</option>';

            };
            echo'</optgroup>
        </select>
```

**2 - On change event, your variable ares the attributes of selected option. JS**

```
$('#patients_list').on('change',function(){  
        var selectedPatient1 = $('#patients_list option:selected').attr('data-pat1'); // $patient[1]
        var selectedPatient2 = $('#patients_list option:selected').attr('data-pat2'); // $patient[2]
  });
```

**PS : I used jQuery in this exemple... I hope it's ok for you...**

Comment: tryed like this:<script type="text/javascript">
 
 $('#patients_list').on('change',function(){  
      var selectedPatient1 = $('#patients_list option:selected').attr('data-pat1'); // $patient[1]
      document.write(selectedPatient1);
      var selectedPatient2 = $('#patients_list option:selected').attr('data-pat2'); // $patient[2]
 });
 
        
</script> but it isn't showing me nothing,srry still learning javascript probabely doing it wrong

Comment: does your option are like    <option value="xx" data-pat1="xx" data-pat2="xx"> optiontext </option>    ??  and do you use jquery ?

Comment: yes i puted the option as you stated in the example above,i wasn't using jquery onlytried now with your example.But gona try with the onchange and with var i = document.getElementById('patients_list');
var username = i.options[i.selectedIndex].value; i can allready get the $patient[0] values now trying to retrive the $patient[1] and $patient[2]